# CGI center image

Tags: perl, cgi

I am having a heck of a time to get this image centered. Any help would be appreciated.

test form at `http://www.quickpaysolutions.com/ttb.html`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

print

    $cgi->header() . 

    img {src => "../cgi-bin/images/mtlogos.png", align=>"CENTER"};

$cgi->start_html( -title => 'Form Results') .

$cgi->center($cgi->h1('Reciept <br> Please Print this Reciept')). "\n";

my @params = $cgi->param();
print '<table border="1" width="600" align="center" cellspacing="1"               cellpadding="2">' . "\n";
foreach my $p (param()) {
    print "<tr><th>$p</th><td>" . $cgi->param($p) . "</td></tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
```

Comment: Try put the image inside a wide table, e.g.: with `width=100%`.

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, to centre an item in a block, set its left and right margins to `auto`:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Using CGI.pm

```
print Tr(
         th(
            { -style=>'margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;' },
            $p
           )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little odd: you are calling `start_html` and `center` and just throwing away the text that they generate without printing it.

`img` isn't a block element, so an `align` attribute of `center` is ignored.

You could just wrap the image in a `center` element:

```
print $cgi->center($cgi->img({ -src => "../cgi-bin/images/mtlogos.png" }));
```

or you could use the `align` attribute on an enclosing element like `div`:

```
$cgi->div({ -align => 'center' }, $cgi->img({ -src => "../cgi-bin/images/mtlogos.png" }));
```

But you should note that both the `center` tag and the `align` attribute are deprecated, and the only proper way to do this is with CSS

Comment: OK I took the img out for now but I will try what you said when I get a chance ...thank you.

Comment: ok this one worked but im am trying some css now   $cgi->div({ -align => 'center' }, $cgi->img({ -src => "../cgi-bin/images/mtlogos.png" }));   thank you so much